# Custom meta box not saving values of radio buttons in Wordpress

Tags: metabox, post-meta, radio

I dont know where i am going wrong.I want to save the values of my radio buttons in custom meta box.Here is my code.

```
<?php

    if (!function_exists('custom_meta_box')) {
        function custom_meta_box(){
            add_meta_box(
                'custom-meta-box',
                __('Post Options', 'spectacularpixels'),
                'post_options_callback',
                'post',
                'normal',
                'high'              
            );
        }
    }

    if (!function_exists('post_options_callback')) {
        function post_options_callback($post_id){

                wp_nonce_field( 'action_layout_nonce', 'name_layout_nonce' );
                $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'my_key', true );

            ?>
                <label for="layout-none">None</label>
                <input type="radio" id="layout-none" name="layout" value="layout-none" <?php checked($value, 'layout-none') ?>>
                <label for="layout-left">Left</label>
                <input type="radio" id="layout-left" name="layout" value="layout-left" <?php checked($value, 'layout-left') ?>>
                <label for="layout-right">Right</label>
                <input type="radio" id="layout-right" name="layout" value="layout-right" <?php checked($value, 'layout-right') ?>>

            <?php
        }
    }

    if (!function_exists('save_meta_data')) {
        function save_meta_data($post_id){

            // Bail if we're doing an auto save
            if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

            // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
            if( !isset( $_POST['name_layout_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['name_layout_nonce'], 'action_layout_nonce' ) ) {echo "nonce error";};

            // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
            if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

            update_post_meta($post_id, 'my_key', $_POST['layout']);
        }
    }
    add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'custom_meta_box');
    add_action('save_post', 'save_meta_data');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are actually being saved - you can always check it in your database.

The problem is in your metabox callback function `post_options_callback` - it is not being called with Post.ID value as an argument, but WP Post object is being passed. Here's revisited piece of code:

```
 function post_options_callback( $post ) {
      $post_id = $post->ID;
```

I also recommend you to not wrap your function with `function_exists` check, but prefix them with unique prefix. Eg: `my_plugin_` (replacing it with your plugin name) or `binda_` (replacing it with you nickname or name).

That way you can be sure that your plugin won't stop working when you install some other plugin defining a function with same name.

Another approach would be to encapsulate your plugin function into a class.

Note: use unique meta_key names as well (prefix them).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with:

echo ($value[0] == 'layout-none')? 'checked="checked"':''; 
echo ($value[0] == 'layout-left')? 'checked="checked"':''; 
echo ($value[0] == 'layout-right')? 'checked="checked"':'';

Complete Updated code:

```
<label for="layout-none">None</label>
                <input type="radio" id="layout-none" name="layout" value="layout-none" <?php echo ($value[0] == 'layout-none')? 'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
                <label for="layout-left">Left</label>
                <input type="radio" id="layout-left" name="layout" value="layout-left" <?php echo ($value[0] == 'layout-left')? 'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
                <label for="layout-right">Right</label>
                <input type="radio" id="layout-right" name="layout" value="layout-right" <?php echo ($value[0] == 'layout-right')? 'checked="checked"':''; ?>>
```